# How to convert Oracle SQL date time into Hive Query format and then perform subtraction?

Tags: sql, oracle, hive, hql, hiveql

I am converting Oracle SQL time to Hive format.

Oracle: `TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE)- INTERVAL '1' MINUTE`

How can I write above in Hive Query?

For this part I can write like this:

```
TO_DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)) )
```

if this is true then how can I subtract `(- INTERVAL '1' MINUTE)`?

Comment: which version of hive are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using version 1.2 or later you can use this command:

```
CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
```

Comment: I need to check. I have connected with Zeppelin. Not aware the version of hive.